# Alpinejs nesting x-data scope issue?

Tags: html, alpine.js

How do I achieve x-data nested x-data component? The "showSingleOrDouble" works but the inner input with click "mainOptions" does not work.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.7.1/dist/alpine.min.js" defer></script>
<div class="showViews" x-data="{mainOptions: 'bienvenida'}">
    <div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="test" @click="mainOptions= 'bienvenida'"> Welcome
            <input type="radio" name="test" @click="mainOptions= categorias"> Categories
        </div>
    </div>
    <main>
        <div x-show="mainOptions === 'bienvenida'">
            Showing this div
        </div>
    // This is the div I want to show
        <div x-show="mainOptions === 'categorias'">
            ....items to show
        </div>
    </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing single quotes around categorias in the `@click` of the `<input>`.
Change:

```
<input type="radio" name="test" @click="mainOptions= categorias"> Categories
```

to:

```
<input type="radio" name="test" @click="mainOptions= 'categorias'"> Categories
```